# "No bootable devices found." after using gparted

Tags: boot, grub2, gparted

My system (Kubuntu 19.10) had been running fine, but it locked up yesterday for some inexplicable reason so I did a manual power down. After that I would boot as normal, I entered the encryption key for my hard drive, and then I would get a black screen and nothing else.

I tried a few things. I booted to recovery mode and tried to fsck, but it didn't like that since the root partition was mounted. So I booted from a Neon USB drive that I had lying around and ran gparted. I used its "check and repair file system" option, and now I get "No bootable devices found." when I don't have the USB drive inserted.

Gparted still shows the partition with the boot flag, but it isn't recognized.

I'm using a Dell laptop, UEFI. I have fiddled with boot order settings to no avail.